# when i make width 100% the elements are not centre aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap...
The problem is container width is not 100%....
How to make it as 100%....
so that everything becomes center aligned and 
In firbug i chnaged the container width to 100% but its not centrally aligned...
how to fix it...

http://jsfiddle.net/WG7kk/1/embedded/result/

```
.container, .navbar-fixed-top .container, .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
width: 940px;
}


<article class="container" style="margin-top: 25px;">


<div id="landing">
    <div class="container">Purchase Order</div>


    <div class="container" >
        <section>
          <div class="row features" >

            <div id="enhancingWidth" class="span6" >


                <div class="span5 left-box">

                    <div class="control-group">

                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Vendor No" id="c_fdCompanyName" name="bcompanyname" value="" required="required">
                            <label class="error" for="c_fdCompanyName" id="c_fdCompanyName_error"></label>
                        </div>
```

Comment: can u explian a bit "The problem is container width is not 100%.... How to make it as 100%.... "

Comment: @XTG: thanks for your reply...I am trying to achieve sth similar to this....by making my text fields to occupy the entire monitor... http://m.espn.go.com/wireless/index?w=1cqmx&i=MCOM

Comment: u mean webpage with 100% of width?

Comment: @XTG: yeah how to make it

Comment: .container, .navbar-fixed-top .container, .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
width: 940px;
} I posted

Comment: try width =100% and use center tag after the main div

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27031/discussion-between-xtg-and-user2136828)

Answer (score 0):

Follow below sample code.

```
    body {
        min-width: 550px;         /* 2 x LC width + RC width */
    }

    #container {
        padding-left: 200px;      /* LC width */
        padding-right: 150px;     /* RC width */
    }

    #container .column {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }

    #center {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #left {
        width: 200px;             /* LC width */
        right: 200px;             /* LC width */
        margin-left: -100%;
    }

    #right {
        width: 150px;             /* RC width */
        margin-right: -100%;
    }

    #footer {
        clear: both;
    }

    /*** IE6 Fix ***/
    * html #left {
        left: 150px;              /* RC width */
    }

    /*** Just for Looks ***/

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #FFF;
    }

    #header, #footer {
        font-size: large;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0.3em 0;
        background: #999;
    }

    #left {
        background: #66F;
    }

    #center {
        background: #DDD;
    }

    #right {
        background: #F66;
    }

    #container .column {
        padding-top: 1em;
        text-align: justify;
    }



  <div id="container">

    <div id="center" class="column">
        <h1>This is the main content.</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="left" class="column">
        <h2>This is the left sidebar.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
    </div>

    <div id="right" class="column">
        <h2>This is the right sidebar.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
    </div>

</div>
```